# Can we add badges to the global inbox?

Tags: feature-request, badges, global-inbox

I don't know how feasible it is, but would it be possible for received badges to be added to the global inbox?

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but IMO the global inbox becomes less helpful the more stuff we cram into it. I already find it nearly useless because of the constant alerts about chat pings

Comment: I agree with @Michael - I don't want to be notified for every single badge I get in the entire network. It might be useful to be notified of my *first* badge of that type on each site, but certainly not *every* badge.

Comment: Ok, how about a new tab in the StackExchange window? Just for badges. Maybe you need a seperate one for chats, too? (I dont know, havent used chats yet).